# Flash AS3 Making sound stop on certain frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, audio, flash-cs5.5

I'm working on an animation that requires "Next" buttons at the end of each scene.
The movie resumes after the button is pressed. During the pause, I'd like the background music to pause as well. I've tried several solutions but none seemed to work.
I am using Flash Professional CS 5.5

Comment: At Least post some code you tried so you can get proper guidance

Answer (score 0):

Assume you are using "timeline" instead pure AS3.
At the start of whole project(MySound is your specified sound):

```
var position:Number = 0;
var mySound:Sound = new MySound();
var sc:SoundChannel;
```

When you start to play every scene(or press on resume button):

```
sc = mySound.play(position);
```

End of scene:

```
position = sc.position;
sc.stop();
```